# material ui always return 0 onchange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

when i try to change the value in autocomplete of `material-ui`, i always get its value 0, here i have uploaded my whole code, can anyone please check my code and help me to resolve this issue ?
any help will  be really appreciated.

```
export default function CreatePIC() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const Department_list = [
    { label: 'Department1', id: 1 },
    { label: 'Department2', id: 2 },
    { label: 'Department3', id: 3 },
    { label: 'Department4', id: 4},
    { label: 'Department5', id: 5 }
  ]

  const [department, setDepartment] = React.useState('');
  
  const handleChangeDepartment = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setDepartment(event.target.value);
  };

return (
<Autocomplete
                          id="Department"
                          value={department}
                          helperText={error.department}
                          options={Department_list}
                          getOptionLabel={option => typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.label}
                          onChange = {handleChangeDepartment}
                          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search Department" variant="outlined" placeholder="Add Department"  />}
                        />
)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ciao, in `Autocomplete` component `event.target.value` will be always 0. If you want to get the selected department you could use `value` in `handleChangeDepartment`. So your code becomes:

```
const handleChangeDepartment = (event, values) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);  // print always 0
    console.log(values);              // print values selected like { label: 'Department1', id: 1 } 
    setDepartment(values.label);      // set department with values.label
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-forked-tp6tu?file=/src/App.js) a codesandbox example.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using:

```
event.target.value
```

try using:

```
event.target.innerText
```

or, to find the option index, use:

```
event.target.dataset.optionIndex
```